# Iterate through object array exclude one key

Tags: javascript

I have this function that iterates through an object array keys and call a function for each one of the keys. What would we the easiest way to skip / ignore two of the keys?

```
Object.entries(newContactInfo).map(([key, value]) => {
  const errorItem = `${key}Error`;
  this.changeErrorValue(!value, errorItem);
});
```

Comment: Use an `if` statement to test the key first...?

Comment: Use forEach with if else condition

Comment: That's not how `.map()` should be used. Use `.forEach()` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**forEach**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) with if else

```
Object.entries(newContactInfo).forEach(([key, value]) => {
  const errorItem = `${key}Error`;
  if(condition as per your requirement here ){
    this.changeErrorValue(!value, errorItem);    
  }
});
```

**On side note** : [**map**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) is supposed to use when you manipulate all the values in some manner and you want them back. for simple iteration use `for` or `forEach`